# Example of Strong Law Failure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

On Wikipedia, an example is given where the weak law of large numbers holds but the strong law does not.  If $X_n$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables with parameter 1 and $Y_n = \frac{\sin(X_n)}{X_n}e^{X_{n}}$, then

$$\frac{\sum_1^nY_{k} - 2/\pi}{n}\rightarrow 0 \hspace{.5cm}\text{(in probability)}$$

To see this, note that we have $y\mathbb{P}(|Y| > y) \le y\int_{\ln(y^{2})}^{\infty}e^{-t}dt = y\frac{1}{y^{2}} = y^{-1}\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow\infty$, using the inequality $\frac{\sin(y)}{y}e^{y}\ge y\implies e^{y}\ge y^{2}$.  Also, $\mathbb{E}(Y1_{|Y|\le n})$ can be shown to converge to $2/\pi$.

But this convergence does not hold almost surely.  How do we know that the (conclusion of the) strong law fails?  In this case, I want to know why the above convergence is not almost sure.

Comment: Have you tried to veryify whether $\mathbb{E}(|Y_1|)$ is finite?

Comment: It is not finite since $\sin(x)/x$ is not Lebesgue integrable by comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: Hence... $ $ $ $

Comment: "I understand why the weak law holds in this case" Hmmm, by the way... why does it?

Comment: @Did This is a good question.  I no longer see why the weak law holds.

Comment: @Did I have edited the question to argue why a weak law holds. I still don't see why this convergence cannot be almost sure.  Based on previous comments, I assume that $\mathbb{E}[|Y|] = \infty$ should imply that this convergence cannot be almost sure, but I don't see why.

Comment: You might start by showing that $Y_k>k$ happens for infinitely many $k$s. Then show the deterministic result that, for every sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n>n$ infinitely often, the sequence of general term $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^ny_k$ diverges.